# How to filter a Swift array by another Swift array knowing that the filter element is a sequence? speed matters

Tags: arrays, swift

I have one Swift array of 10,000 structs:

```
struct Book {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var pages: Int?
    var words: Int?
}

var firstArray: [Book] = [] // contains 10,000 elements
```

and I have a second Swift array of type Int, with 5,000 elements:

```
var secondArray: [Int] = [] // contains 5,000 elements
```

I want to filter the firstArray by removing all elements in it where the id field (Book.id) is not contained in the secondArray.

Knowing that Book.id is unique for every element in firstArray and also in a sequence (from small to large). eg. 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 10, 14, 15, 16, 40, 50, 51, etc. (some numbers may be skipped)

The secondArray is also unique and in a sequence (small to large)

What is the fastest way to filter firstArray in Swift 4?

Knowing that the arrays are a sequence the filtering should become quicker as we process the array right? Meaning if we are half-way through the firstArray, we will only be looping through half of firstArray searching for a match in the secondArray. Same for secondArray, as the array will become smaller every time we find a match.   Does this all make sense?

Hope someone out there knows how to do this. I've seen this done on Android (Kotlin), but how to do it in Swift?

I think in Kotlin it is like this:

```
firstArray?.let { dataFirstArray ->
        secondArray?.let {
            firstArray = ArrayList(dataFirstArray.asSequence().filter { dataSecondArray -> dataSecondArray in it }.toList())
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sets are far faster than arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `id` always exists, don't make it optional.

```
struct Book {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
    var pages: Int?
    var words: Int?
}
```

The simplest way to filter is a single line:

```
func filter1(firstArray:[Book],secondArray:[Int]) -> [Book]
{
    return firstArray.filter{secondArray.contains($0.id)}
}
```

I also tried to make use of the fact that the arrays are sorted by doing this:

```
func filter2(firstArray:[Book],secondArray:[Int]) -> [Book]
{
    var j = 0;

    return firstArray.filter{
        while(j < secondArray.count && secondArray[j] < $0.id)
        {
            j += 1
        }
        if(j < secondArray.count && $0.id == secondArray[j])
        {
            j += 1
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

As suggested by comment, I also tried using `Set`:

```
func filter3(firstSet:Set<Book>,secondSet:Set<Int>) -> Set<Book>
{
    return firstSet.filter{secondSet.contains($0.id)}
}
```

Tested with the following code:

```
var firstArray: [Book] = (0..<10000).map{Book(id: $0, name: nil, pages: nil, words: nil)}.filter {_ in Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0}
var secondArray: [Int] = (0..<10000).filter{_ in Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0}

var timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let result1 = filter1(firstArray: firstArray, secondArray: secondArray)
print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - timestamp)

timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let result2 = filter2(firstArray: firstArray, secondArray: secondArray)
print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - timestamp)

timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
let result3 = filter3(firstArray: firstArray, secondSet: Set(secondArray))
print(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 - timestamp)
```

test result:

```
2.687404155731201
0.0014042854309082031
0.002758026123046875
```

Hope this help

Comment: Yes, I am. Is it a bad idea?

Comment: kkk yes you need to use a real project

Comment: Yeah, a macOS command line app is a much better way to test Swift performance. A playground is about the worst.

Comment: Thanks, added test results on iPad and macOS command line app.

Comment: The suggestion of matt means only using `Set<Int>`, not `Set<Book>`.

Comment: On my data set I'm getting these timings:

`result1: 13.445518970489502
result2: 0.015350103378295898
result3: 0.10524106025695801`

Comment: One more, your `filter2` does not return right results when ids in `[Book]` _may be skipped_. Please check the result with `var firstArray: [Book] = (0..<10000).map{Book(id: $0, name: nil, pages: nil, words: nil)}.filter {_ in Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0}` and `var secondArray: [Int] = (0..<10000).filter{_ in Int.random(in: 0...1) == 0}`. (Assuming Xcode 10/Swift 4.2)

Comment: yeah, just notice that. Edited to account for that situation. Surprisingly `filter3` always nearly double the time of `filter2`

Comment: Yes, it shows nearly the same results as yours when I tested your latest code on my old MacBook. Maybe `hashValue` cannot generate effective values for hashing random numbers. Seems your `filter2` shows the best performance in average given the condition of the OP.

Comment: tried changing `Book` from `struct` to `class` and use `id` as `hashValue`. The difference is reduced from 2 times to about 1.65 times :)

Comment: With your updated answer,
On my data set I'm getting these timings:

`result1: 8.464757919311523`
`result2: 1.0284819602966309`
`result3: 0.04727792739868164`

Comment: In filter2, why do you add one step every time? It seems a binary search in this step to me. That can speed up for random distribution sometimes.